# When do you get paid for the heists?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

After the heist you play Trevor for a bit and then goes back to Michael. But when do you actually receive the money from the heist?

Comment: Can you clarify which heist you are talking about?

Answer (score 1):

After the jewellery heist, I had some time playing but I did not receive the payment either. Then I called Lester (from Michael's cell phone) but he didn't answer (had busy tone). A few seconds later, Lester gave me a call and he said that he transferred the money into my account. I checked and saw the money in my account. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

> You will get paid after you kil Trevor or Franklin or the third  choice of the deal when Devin Westin comes to your house trying to convince you to kill one of the two

Comment: *Spoiler Alert* (I'm sure most people have finished the game BUT who really knows...)